# Removing elements from list of dictionaries based on condition

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have a list of dictionaries

```
lst = [{'match': 0,
  'ref_title': ['dog2', 'title1'],
  'matching_string': 'dog2',
  'display_string': 'dog2'},
 {'match': 0,
  'ref_title': ['dog2', 'cat'],
  'matching_string': 'dog2',
  'display_string': 'dog2'},
 {'match': 2,
  'ref_title': ['dog2', 'dog'],
  'matching_string': 'dog',
  'display_string': 'dog2'}]
```

I am trying to make a new list, based on the following conditions:

- If match = 2 or 1, keep only the dictionaries with match = 2 or 1.
- If match = 0, make new list empty.

So for the above case, I want to achieve

```
[{'match': 2,
  'ref_title': ['dog2', 'dog'],
  'matching_string': 'dog',
  'display_string': 'dog2'}]
```

How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: which list do you want to make it empty?

Comment: Can you please update your question and put there expected result?

Comment: If match = 0, then do nothing. I am having the problem of appending the 0 matches if there is match 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1):

```py
newlst = [d for d in lst if d.get('match') in {1,2}]
```

This also handles the corner case (spurious data) where some of the `dict`s were somehow missing a `'match'` key.

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [{'match': 0,
  'ref_title': ['dog2', 'title1'],
  'matching_string': 'dog2',
  'display_string': 'dog2'},
 {'match': 0,
  'ref_title': ['dog2', 'cat'],
  'matching_string': 'dog2',
  'display_string': 'dog2'},
 {'match': 2,
  'ref_title': ['dog2', 'dog'],
  'matching_string': 'dog',
  'display_string': 'dog2'}]


new_lst = [dct for dct in lst if dct['match'] == 1 or dct['match'] == 2]
print(new_lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

try as follows:

`match_finder` checks if values 1 or 2 are in 'match' to satisfy your first condition. If this case is not satisfied it goes to check if match=0, which will return empty list.

```
lst = [{'match': 0,
'ref_title': ['dog2', 'title1'],
'matching_string': 'dog2',
'display_string': 'dog2'},
{'match': 0,
'ref_title': ['dog2', 'cat'],
'matching_string': 'dog2',
 'display_string': 'dog2'},
 {'match': 2,
  'ref_title': ['dog2', 'dog'],
  'matching_string': 'dog',
  'display_string': 'dog2'}]


def match_finder(lst):
    ks = [m['match'] for m in lst]

    if 1 in ks or 2 in ks:
        return [i for i in lst if i['match'] in {1,2}]
    elif 0 in ks:
        return []
    else:
        return None

match_finder(lst)
```